# SPA on AWS S3 bucket using CloudFront with non WWW

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I’m deploying a SPA in a S3 bucket. I’m using cloudfront to work through https. I need to redirect or delete the www in my domain (example.com). I tried this process:

- create a s3 bucket to the www domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and redirect all requests to the default domain (example.com)
- create a distribution for www domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))
- create an A type record in Route53 that points to the www distribution

The result is that it’s not redirecting to the non-www bucket. What is happening is that its waiting to find index.html (configured in the default root object) of the www bucket and is thus not redirecting to the other bucket (the non www one)

**This is my S3 configuration:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And Cloudfront configuration:**
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post more details of the S3 bucket and Cloudfront config?

Comment: I updated the question, I have added the details. Thanks @jellycsc

Comment: Can you also show the origin domain name in CloudFront config?

Comment: It is www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com (I'm using a dummy domain for private reasons)

Comment: Bingo, this is the root cause. Could you change it to the [s3 website endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html)?

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't work. If I use the URL that S3 provides me (static web configuration part) the redirection works, but the issue is in cloudfront, it response with the index.html of the www bucket

Comment: Can you invalidate the cache with `/*`?

Comment: Thanks bro, It is working

Comment: NP. Please consider accepting my answer below if you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OP's feedback in the comment section, changing the CloudFront origin to use the website endpoint works.